# Remove Freeze Button Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I'd like to remove the Freeze and Hide Buttons from my Interactive Grid, whenever I  click on a column header.

[image]

Problem is, I already had a solution previously when using Apex 5.1, though now that it's been upgraded to the 18.2 version, it doesn't seem to work anymore. This was the code I used before:

```
$("#grid_id").on("gridactivatecolumnheader", function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#grid_id").find("[data-option='freeze']").remove();
        $("#grid_id").find("[data-option='hide']").remove();
    },
               1);
}
            );
```

I've tried other versions that I found online that sadly did nothing, such as the following:

```
function(config) {
    config.features = config.features || {};
    config.features.freeze = false;
    config.features.hide= false;
    return config;
}
```

Have these functions become deprecated on the latest version? Is there another way to hide these features? The Oracle Developer only really allows for the disabling of the Sort/Control Break/Aggregate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#id").on("gridactivatecolumnheader", function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#id_ig_column_header_menu").find("[data-option='freeze']").remove();
        $("#id_ig_column_header_menu").find("[data-option='hide']").remove();
    },1);
});
```

They change how that options is rendered in your HTML, the code above works. You need to find that options inside the "#id_ig_column_header_menu" and not just "#id".

This resolve your problem today, tomorrow they can change this again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll make sure to check that when I can see the code again.

Comment: It did work, thanks! Hopefully it won't be changed or patched anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Go to column attribute > advanced > javaScript Initialization code >

```
function(config) { 
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
        noHeaderActivate: true 
    };  
    return config; 
}
```

Comment: Does not work in APEX 21.2